# Installing packages from source into EPD Python on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, import

I recently compiled the shogun library from source, but I'm not sure where I need to place the python files created.  make install placed them in '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages' which I assume is valid on linux systems.

sys.path in python doesn't have a dist-packages in its path, only a site-packages

Answer (score 0):

When you configure shogun, you need to specify the python path.

http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/doc/en/current/installation.html

```
./configure --pydir /path to epd
```

Then remake and reinstall.

Comment: Setting that appears to just place the python files in the '/usr/local/lib/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/'

Comment: Is that where EPD installed?  I don't have a Mac right now to compare to.

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/ is where python is installed.

The installer for shogun seems to have added /usr/local/lib/ itself.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Decided to simply add a `.pth` file to my site-packages directory which points to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

That is: Place in `/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages`
a file `shogun.pth` which simply contains: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`